# Tools for getting runtime or compile time details

Tags: java

Is there any tool or plugin that will show me address of variable ,memory diagram,function calling stack etc at program run time or compile time.
(i am using eclipse juno).

Comment: and why do you need this ? perhaps you could use a debugger that is already provided with eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Preface: usually questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. But the asked tools can be found in the JDK itself, so:</sup>

---

There are two already included in the JDK itself: look for `jvisualvm` and `jconsole` in the `bin` folder of your JDK.

Also what you're asking can be viewed in an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans if you run your application in debug mode.

Documentation of [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html):

> Java VisualVM is useful to Java application developers to troubleshoot applications and to monitor and improve the applications' performance. Java VisualVM can allow developers to generate and analyse heap dumps, track down memory leaks, perform and monitor garbage collection, and perform lightweight memory and CPU profiling. Plug-ins also exist that expand the functionality of Java VisualVM. For example, most of the functionality of the JConsole tool is available via the MBeans Tab and JConsole Plug-in Wrapper plug-ins. You can choose from a catalog of standard Java VisualVM plug-ins by selecting 'Tools' | 'Plugins' in the Java VisualVM menus.

Documentation of [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html):

> The JConsole graphical user interface is a monitoring tool that complies to the Java Management Extensions (JMX) specification. JConsole uses the extensive instrumentation of the Java Virtual Machine (Java VM) to provide information about the performance and resource consumption of applications running on the Java platform.

For an external one, check out [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).